# How to enable windows keys (pg up/pg down) on apple wireless keyboard on PC

Tags: keyboard, wireless, updown

Not very development related question but still.

I have PC + Windows 7 + Apple wireless keyboard. Struggling to find a way to have pg up/pg down or home/end functionality out of it. No luck so far. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

The way keys work on a Mac for that functionality is:

```
fn + up arrow key -> page up
fn + down arrow key -> page down

command + left -> front of the line
command + right -> end of the line
```

This will also depend on if key mappings are set up correctly.

Comment: Ok Mac - that works indeed. However I'm on Windows 7 - and this sequence doesn't work there at all. I know how to use google to find such obvious answers, but no-one told yet how to achieve these buttons' functionality on Windows 7 on PC. Thus - I resided to posting a question here.